# Vue.js not persisting select box info in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I have the following select box in my Rails app:

```
<div id="vue-element">
  <strong><%= f.label :property_type %></strong><br>
  <%= f.select(:property_type, options_for_select(@types.map {|type| [type.titleize, type]}, listing.property_type), {'v-model': 'propertyType'}) %>
</div>
```

but when I try to display the content of propertyType on the same page, Vue is not rendering the selected entry:

```
{{ propertyType }}
```

This is how I instantiate vue.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-element',
  data: {
    propertyType: undefined
  }
})
```

Any idea why this may be or how I can debug this?
Thanks in advance!

**The fix:**

I was missing an empty set of curly braces:

```
<%= f.select(:property_type, options_for_select(@types.map {|type| [type.titleize, type]}, listing.property_type), {}, {'v-model': 'propertyType'}) %>
```

Comment: Use View Source. What is rendered in `#vue-element`? Also, are any of the select options selected?

Comment: Something like `<select name="listing[property_type]" id="listing_property_type"><option value="apartment">Apartment</option> <option value="castle">Castle</option> <option value="house">House</option> </select>`. Am I supposed to also be seeing `v-model="propertyType"` on the select element?

Comment: Are you inspecting or viewing the source? If you inspect, then you wouldn't necessarily see the v-model because Vue would remove it. If you are viewing source, then you should in order for Vue to work.

Comment: Ah right! I didn't know that. I was inspecting. Yes the problem indeed seems to be that the `v-model` attribute is not present. I'll look into adding it.

Comment: Yep, that would be a rails question then and I can't help you further :)

Answer (score 0):

Summarising based on the comments and your own fix with some additional info that may help future users.

- Confirm if `v-model` is present in the HTML

  - View Source
  - Do not Inpect elements using Dev Tools as this will not show `v-model`
- If `v-model` is not in the source, there is most likely a problem with the formatting of the `select` method

  - Format: `select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)` [API docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/select)
  - Because `options` and `html_options` both accept a hash, it's safer to explicitly include both so Ruby knows how to parse it (even if that means including an empty hash).

```rb
### Correct examples

# multi-line format for readability
# select(
#  method, 
#  choices = nil, 
#  options = {}, 
#  html_options = {}
# )

# no `options` provided, but explicit empty `options` hash '{}' ('The fix' in the original post)
<%= f.select(
  :property_type, # method
  options_for_select(@types.map {|type| [type.titleize, type]}, listing.property_type), # choices
  {}, # options
  {'v-model': 'propertyType'} # html_options
) %>

# with `options` values
<%= f.select(
  :property_type, # method
  options_for_select(@types.map {|type| [type.titleize, type]}, listing.property_type), #choices
  {include_blank: 'Select your type...'}, # options
  {'v-model': 'propertyType'} # html_options
) %>
```